# "Ain't ... no more" is "am not ... [any more]"?

Tags: negative-polarity-items, aint

First of all, I ain't a native speaker.
And one of the most confusing sentences to me is

> I ain't going to this place no more.

*Ain't* in this sentence basically means *am not*, so it translates to *I am not going to this place no more*.

What exactly does *no more* in this sentence mean? Does it have the same meaning as *any more*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points to make here:

- *Ain't* is a dialectal variant and is considered nonstandard, especially in writing.
  Use *am not* instead in writing.
- Using *no more* after a negative is also a dialectal variant, with the same written status.
  Written English and most spoken dialects use a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), like *any more*,
  instead of using another negative, like *no more*, a process that's called [Negative Concord](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf).
  Negative concord is very common in many languages, like Spanish -- *No tengo nada* translates as 'I have nothing' or 'I don't have anything', but literally means "I don't have nothing",
  since ***no*** and ***nada*** are both negatives. But English prefers NPIs, which are all idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so clearly :).  I totally get ot now:)

Answer (score 3):

The sentence means *I am not going to go to that place anymore.*  Or *I am going to go to that place no more.* Or *I will not go to that place anymore.* Or *I will no longer go to that place.*

*This place* should be *that place*, since the verb is *go*, not *come*.  The *not...no more* is more correctly expressed without the double negative, as *not...anymore* or *...no more*.

And since you mean future, use *going to go* or *will go*, not *going*.

Comment: _Go_ and _come_ do not map exactly to _this_ and _that_ in English. There is nothing wrong with the phrase “I am not going to this place anymore” in the right context. If you’re standing in a bar, say, and have for some reason just decided you are never going to that bar again, you would be just as likely to use _go_ as _come_, since the idiom is ‘go to a bar’. Similarly, the present continuous can be used for the future just fine: “I’m never doing that again” is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, of course. Both *go* and *come* are general, and so are *that* and *this*.  Context helps.  And you will be understood regardless of the combination you use, even when no idiom is involved.  I nevertheless stand by my general suggestion here in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I respect that you aren't completely familiar with the modern English language (and I hope I don't accidentally insult you). "I ain't going to this place no more" is considered by some as a double negative, or two 'not' words cancelling out each other. However, sentences already mentioned by Drew can substitute for this former (and maybe still in use??) type of grammar.